# Gulp-sass compiles CSS when a typo in code but without error

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm had updated to gulp 4 from gulp 3 and also updated the remaining packages, gulp-sass was among them (update from 4.0.1 to 4.0.2), but then it has stopped compile to CSS properly. When i have a typo *outside* the SCSS block the gulp-sass still compilling into CSS, but without appearing any error. Hence my layout crashes in place where the typo was between the blocks.

For example:

```css
//SCSS

typo   //hmm, it's ok, let's break the layout

.soc {
  typo   //an error was detected
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

The console in first case is clear and quiet, only "Finished 'sass' after XX ms".

---

An example how it compiles to css:

```css
//SCSS

TYPO

.burger {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #E3CD56;
  }
  &:active {
    background-color: #DBAA35;
    transition: none;
  }
}
```

Just compiles to:

```css
//CSS

TYPO
.burger {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; }
  TYPO
.burger:hover {
    background-color: #E3CD56; }
  TYPO
.burger:active {
    background-color: #DBAA35;
    transition: none; }
```

Comment: Have a look at this, maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860135/gulp-sass-not-showing-any-errors

Comment: @Morpheus unfortunately this is not my case, i already have an error handler and when i have, let's say, a typo inside block there is pop a message in the console related to this type error.